# Parents surname do not match with my passport. I need to apply for a Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas

Please help me. I am staying in Germany and planning to bring my parents for a short visit. The issue is different surnames in my passport vs their passports.

Can I go ahead and apply for a visa or do I need to apply for a new passport and correct their names?

Please let me know.

Comment: Their passports should match their names. Many people have different last names from their parents.

Comment: But their names are mentioned in my passport. So parents names in my passport has different surname than their actual passport. So I am afraid that visa officer might question that your parents name mentioned in visa form do not match with the name in tour passport. 
I might be overthinking, just wanted some feedback if anyone else also has same situation.

Comment: Why are their names different? If you have the name change documented just show it, it's a no brainier.

Comment: I feel this question needs more info about why there's a difference - is it a name change, spelling differences, marriage, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

**This is not a problem**.  Parents' names are not included in the biometric passport standard, and [they are not included at all on Indian passports issued since 2018](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/coming-soon-orange-passports-sans-parents-name/article22430770.ece).  The officer processing your Schengen application will not look for them, much less expect them to match.

Comment: Can we make this question into a canonical question on parents names in Indian passports?